# Passing string with space character as parameter to on-click function generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My hypertlink  generated by JavaScript is as follows:

> ```
> '<a href="#" onClick=passSearchTerm("' +aa + '");>View</a>'
> ```

The parameter passes wells when the string  is as follows:

> ```
> var aa = 'TAGS(\\"ab\\")';
> ```

I confirmed it by alerting inside the function

> function passSearchTerm(aa)
>         { 
>              alert(aa);
>          }

However, this wont alert when the var is defined as follows:

> var aa = 'TAGS(\"a b\")';  //space between "a" and "b"

Can anyone suggest me how to pass such string? Thanks in advance for your help.
Actually I am trying to pass likely following string:

> TAGS("a or b")

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: What does your method `TAGS` do?

Comment: TAGS too is part of String i want to pass, like consider another sting instead var a='apple(\"a or b\')'

Comment: @THiCE , tags is aslo a part of string

Comment: @THiCE: What `TAGS()` returns is irrelevant. The problem here is how to pass the `string` `"TAGS("a or b")"` to a inline onclick.

Comment: @Cerbrus THiCE's question addresses the ambiguity of whether `TAGS(...)` is actually supposed to be a function call instead of a string literal, as in `onclick="callSomeFunc(callAnother('string arg'))"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While generating ur hyperlink by javascript use encodeURIComponent 
ex.

```
"<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"passSearchTerm('" + encodeURIComponent(aa) + "')\">View</a>"
```

and while retriving use decodeURIComponent

```
function passSearchTerm(aa) { alert(decodeURIComponent(aa)); }
```

Comment: thank you! encodeURIComponent did the trick for me... I was going crazy with this problem and I cannot make the code actually good because I'm just doing maintenace for a web app and I just needed to fix this little but annoying bug.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've just overused your escapes.

This works for me.

```
  var aa = 'TAGS("a b")'; 
  // var aa =  'TAGS(\"a b\")'; 

  var e = document.createElement("A");
  e.href = "#";
  e.setAttribute( "onClick", "passSearchTerm('" + aa + "');" );
  e.innerText = "View";

  document.body.appendChild(e);

  function passSearchTerm(p){
    alert(p);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aa = 'TAGS(\\"a&nbsp;b\\")';
```

This code does work. It is because in html space should written as `&nbsp;`

**[update]**

Here is the full example. http://jsfiddle.net/YAJNL/

Comment: No it shouldnt! Read http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.3.2.2

Comment: @Adrian: You should use it with the code provided by the questioner. http://jsfiddle.net/YAJNL/ here is the full code example.

Comment: You mean the code with a mistake in it? The mistake is incorrectly escaping the various nested " or ' characters. To say you should use a No-Break Space, here looks wrong. Fixing the Escapes is much more useful and 'looks' some much better. If you fix the escapes, the code then 'works' with either a regular space or &nbsp; ... Although I would still maintain that its correct to use a regular space, as subsequent parsing of the string may stumble on &nbsp; . a Space is encoded as /u0020 and &nbsp; as /u00A0 internally.